# How to Read Google Analytics Campaign String to Personalize Component in Sitecore

Tags: google-analytics, sitecore

We are using Sitecore 7.0, and want to use a rule to read the "utm_campaign=campaign1" out of the url string to personalize a content block.

Does anybody know which rule accomplishes this? Hoping to use the Sitecore interface and not use custom coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff,

Out of the box Sitecore DMS does not have a builtin rule to personalize off of a query string.  You would need to add some custom code to have this custom DMS rule.

There is already a very detailed blog written describing exactly how to create this type of custom DMS query string rule that you can find here:

http://blogs.perficient.com/portals/2012/12/14/sitecore-dms-in-action-querystringcondition/

If you follow these steps you will be able to add this type of personalization via the standard DMS Personalize interface without additional custom coding.

Comment: I read that blogged and it looked helpful, if I had the comfort level to add code to the site.

It seems like a serious defect that a DMS in today's marketing world wouldn't be able to read query strings.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sitecore is a platform that always requires some type of customization for any type of real implementation.  The customization described in the blog article would be considered very light in terms of complexity and supportability.  There are also many other ways to handle your specific problem if we had a better understanding of your requirements.  Many implementations of this would us Goals to drive the personalization although that would also require a bit of custom code to achieve.

Comment: Agreed it is light and that customization is always necessary.  We use a development agency and can ask them to make the change.

I was just surprised after seeing all the built in rule sets that reading a url string wouldn't be out-of-the-box.

My requirements are to place a content block with a video in it only when the url string includes "utm_campaign=video" as we have several display ads pointing at the landing page and just want to tweak the landing page based on the ad that was clicked.